# library for loading 3d model into webgl

Tags: 3d, webgl

I want to build a web viewer for 3d objects and scenes. There are various format and I want to know are there any converters that can read and load 3d model, material and animation into my viewer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [XML3D](http://xml3d.org/about/)

> The design of XML3D allows seamless integration of 3D content into HTML pages. The interactive 3D content can be embedded directly into the HTML content. This way, 3D content can be displayed in arbitrary websites without any plug-in being installed.

You asked:

*are there any converters that can read and load 3d model*

Yes there are converters to convert your models to XML3D.
https://github.com/xml3d/xml3d.js/wiki/Converting-models-to-XML3D

Answer (score 0):

If you have engineering models from desktop applications, like .RVT/.DWG/.IPT (and others), you might consider [this viewing technology](http://developer.autodesk.com/api/viewerapi/). It can work linked to the server or "offline" (i.e. on your own server, [see this sample](http://extract.autodesk.io)).

The webservice provide translation and viewing, but you can use only translation and get the [three.js](http://threejs.org/) objects and expand it.

For more samples, visit [this github repository](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk).